# How does a patent owner establsh that a patent that includes an algorithm is infringed?

Tags: software, algorithms

If I steal someone's algorithm, how would anyone be able to prove that I am using their algorithm? Only I have access to the code for the algorithm?

Unless someone sees my code, they can't say what algorithm is actually being executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

George White's answer succinctly gives an answer to this question in its context, the only thing I could add from a more technical perspective, since I sense there is some curiosity from that angle is that:

You can only patent algorithms in a coupled with other tangible components  as part of a system, method or computer program product, and not merely the algorithm itself, and that only. It may seem a technicality, but I sense this questions taps into that, and it is, in fact, an important consideration: Not seeing your code does not mean one is unable to define the process flow of software.

For example: If, upon approaching my car's door a camera coupled with all the necessary hardware and software to verify its me, opens or unlocks the door, from a *patent* perspective, if the method of opening a car door in this way (or the system comprising of all the hardware and software components for this) is able to do this as such as is described in a granted patent (or potentially a provisional patent) if the *necessary* components of the system, including a process flow of the software, regardless if the code itself is written or even structured differently (this is not copyright!), if it actually goes through the same steps generally defined in a patent application, for example, in a flow chart or verbally described step by step, it will be a patent infringement still.

In some cases this can be proven merely by what the software does. Even simply wedging in extra steps in the process flow that does not substantially improve, and neither does it worsen or impair the software component, it will likely be violative any ways.

But, generally, it all comes down to the steps set forth in the software component: If those match, and it can be, with reasonable probability, proven that they are infringing, the actual way the code is written and/or structured is a distinction without a difference in the eye of patent law, a suit can be merited, and the steps may ensue that George White described on court.

Comment: It is true that that, *in some cases*, the details of the code may not be required to judge infringement if a claim. It depends on the claim.  

Patents do not cover results but the specific apparatus or steps that achieve results. In the example of a car that unlocks itself based on visual information, a claim might or might not be specific to the way images are judged. One method might use face recognition and another might use recognition of gait. It might or might not be readily apparent without opening up the software which is being used and the claim in question could be specific.

Comment: Adding a step to make a non-infringing improvement is flat wrong. If you have all the steps of a claim, adding other steps can’t make your product non-fringing. Removing a step can avoid infringement but never adding a step. Two smaller points are that it is misleading to suggest that a patent application is judged by “improvement” over something else. Improvement is not a criteria for patentability. Last,  the word “anticipate” has a technical meaning in patent law that relates to novelty and it is being used here in a context of obviousness. They are quite different concepts.

Comment: Generally, whether something is useful or not is not a matter of patentability, and therefore the degree of relative usefulness to prior art should also not be a matter of consideration, but in specific cases: It is. When justifying the lack of obviousness as a result of combining, as it is most typical, multiple inventions, an examiner may be compelled to arguing as to why one would combine certain prior arts which typically, more often than not, comes down to a debate around the objective as to why one would combine certain prior arts, and there, improvement is a key and central question as

Comment: ...the usefulness and relative usefulness to the cited prior arts determines whether an invention is non-obvious or anticipated by the prior art by a person of ordinary skill in the art.

Comment: I agree with the first comment although I would assume that one unable to show that an alleged infringers solution takes the certain steps of the softwares process flow _and_ that it delivers the expected result, a case would be thrown out of court as vexatious litigation; If one can show the result, it may or may not be taken up by a court; if one can show that the process flow included the steps, I’d expect that would merit an action and discovery to see if the process flow includes non-obvious intermediary steps or includes a substantially different step in place of a step part of the patnt

Comment: “Adding a step to make a non-infringing improvement is flat wrong” generally “wrong”, that is, unlikely to yield the result to overcome obviousness, is true; “flat wrong”, as it can under no circumstances overcome obviousness, I would disagree. For one, the definition of a step in itself is vague enough; a process flow may be set forth on different levels of abstraction. As you pointed out: A self-unlocking/self-opening vehicle may use not only facial recognition, but for e.g. gait recognition; on a certain level of abstraction, either can undertake the step of “recognizing the user”.

Comment: The description will likely include a non-exclusive list of examples as to what specific solutions (if well-known in the art) or sets of sub steps the software component must actually execute (if the solution was so novel that a single-word or other short reference would not suffice for a person with ordinary skill in the art to know what that step would entail). Adding an intermediary step to adjust the car to the user profile of the driver (incl. adjust the height of the seat, the wheel, its distance, angle, lumbar support, screens’ brightness, parental control speed limit etc.) may be...

Comment: , as in this example, be dozens of steps. The level of abstraction of defining what a “step” is does allow in not a negligible cases, whether an intermediary step can be non-obvious; a step added after the last step of a patent before process flow cycle starts over will be within the patent’s scope in all cases.

Comment: I agree that the concept of improvement can be a factor in an obviousness analysis regarding motivation to combine.  In other comments I think you may be conflating infringement and patentability. The patentability of something is irrelevant to the question of infringement. If all steps of an issued patent are present then there is infringement - period. It is irrelevant if added steps make the new product patentable or not. This is a frequent confusion. Patenting your invention does not provide immunity from infringing an earlier invention that yours is a proper superset of.

Comment: Now I’m very surprised! Are you saying that if a process flow includes A-B-C steps, and one replaces “B” with a non-obvious “D”, for one, allowing for a patent (in this hypothetical) that would _under no circumstances_ also mean that A-D-C, as a whole, would not be an infringement presuming neither A, B or C steps, in and of themselves are patents on their own merit? (Of course, if A is patented as an independent claim elsewhere, including the step is an infringement of A, but A-D-C should not be infringing A-B-C, only the parts or combinations that are actually claimed and granted, no?

Comment: No - removing a step would create something that does not infringe. I understood you to suggest that adding a step could also lead to non infringement. Replacing a step would not infringe unless under the doctrine of equivalents. You are still focused on non obviousness. It is only an issue when determining patentability not infringement. In judging if replacing B with D removed infringement we do not judge anything about obviousness, only *equivalence* under the DOE.

Comment: That part is reassuring! So, then, say, wedging D between B and C when D, in itself, is non-obvious and claimed and granted as an independent claim after the grant of A-B-C, would A-B-D-C infringe A-B-C? (I sense it will after thinking more about your comment: You need to also use substantially similar hardware components in the solution or method which must not be or be related to a generic computer and presuming at least one random piece of hardware, like a camera, it feels to resonate with a common sense of justice as to why that shouldn’t be eligible — would still be understood as a [...]

Comment: [...] a system or method substantially based on the other or reinventing it. But still: So should I understand this as even if we ad D through Z, each novel and non-obvious, obtaining a patent thereon and using the invention thereafter would be infringement of A-B-C?

Comment: Yes if it has A B and C it infringes a claim . . .comprising A B C.  Adding D makes no difference whether  it is “obvious” or not. You might want to edit your answer.

Comment: Interesting! I’m greatly surprised now. I hold a couple of patents and worked with some of the most prominent patent law firms of the U.S., and Hungary for the past 12 years, and still. Added the edit.

Answer (score 4):

In civil lawsuits, including patent infringement,there is something called [*discovery*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_(law)) where a judge requires the defendant to expose information relevant to the case to the plaintive.

Also, patent owners can attempt to reverse-engineer products to look for infringement. It is not only software. Integrated circuits can be analyzed by pealing away layers. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13472/is-it-possible-to-reverse-engineer-a-chip-design

See answer to similar question [How is patent infringement usually being discovered?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/18426/how-is-patent-infringement-usually-being-discovered?rq=1)